# If $A$ is a square matrix, then $A=P+Q$ for $P$ symmetric, $Q$ antisymmetic.

Tags: linear-algebra

This is what's to be shown.

> If $A$ is a square matrix, then $A$ can be taken apart *uniquely* into two matrices $P+Q$, such that $P$ is symmetric and $Q$ is antisymmetric.

This is my work so far:

$A$ can always be taken apart into some $P+Q$.
Since $Q$ is to be antisymmetric, it must follow that $Q+Q^t = 0$. Since $Q$ and $Q^t$ have the same diagonal entries, all of them must be $0$. So $P$ must have the same diagonal entries as $A$. This is all good, but I'm stuck here. I'm trying to work my way backwards, trying to see how the elements in $P$ and $Q$ must be related to each other, but I just cant seem to find any rhyme or reason in the elements off the diagonal.

Intuition tells me that if $P$'s elements are the same as $A$, and $Q$'s are all $0$, then this should be enough to prove uniqueness. Any tips?

I don't think this should be too hard, so it's kinda frustrating getting stuck! :(

This is not homework, or classwork of any kind, this is for my own pleasure.

Comment: If $A$ has such a decomposition, what does $A^t$ then look like?

Comment: Consider $a_{ij}+a_{ji} = p_{ij}+p_{ji}+q_{ij}+q_{ji}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hints:

If $A=P+Q$ with $P$ symmetric and $Q$ antisymmetric, then $A^\top=P^\top+Q^\top=P-Q$.

Solve for $P$ in terms of $A$, then solve for $Q$ in terms of $A$.

---

The only blip to remember with this reasoning is that it doesn't work in a fields of characteristic $2$ (where $2$ isn't a unit.) In those cases, "symmetric" and "antisymmetric" mean the same thing, and this decomposition can't happen.

Comment: Now I get it, A = 1/2(A+A^t) + 1/2(A-A^t) = P+Q, both naturally exist and are unique! Now it's chrystal clear! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You already have your answer, but here is another way to show uniqueness without knowing what $P$ and $Q$ are explicitly. Suppose that
$$P+Q = P'+Q'$$
where $P,P'$ are symmetric and $Q,Q'$ are antisymmetric. Then
$$P-P' = Q'-Q,$$
so the symmetric matrix $P-P'$ equals the antisymmetric matrix $Q'-Q$. The only matrix which is both symmetric and antisymmetric is the zero matrix, so $P-P'=0$ and $Q'-Q=0$, showing that $P=P'$ and $Q=Q'$.

Comment: My thoughts exactly +1